# Git sees a changed file in an ignored directory, but does not report it

Tags: git, gitignore

Git does not allow me to switch branches in a clean working directory. Instead it tells me a file in an ignored folder would be overridden.

```
$ git status
# On branch ECP-2229
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git checkout ECP-2243
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        c.t.e.server.logback/bin/logback.xml
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

There are hundreds of files in this and other bin/ folders in this working directory, all of them ignored.

```
$ cat .gitignore
bin
```

I assumed that the file would be already tracked somehow and tried to remove it, but

```
$ git rm c.t.e.server.logback/bin/logback.xml
fatal: pathspec 'c.t.e.server.logback/bin/logback.xml' did not match any files
```

What is wrong with this file and how can I convince git that it does not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason someone tracked `logback.xml`, and you have an untracked version of this file. So git warns you that your untracked version will be overwritten by checkout, which is good, even if it is in `.gitignore` (who knows it doesn't contain value?).

You fail to `git rm` it because yours is untracked, so unknown to git, `git rm` only works on tracked or staged files.

Instead just `rm` it and you'll be fine.